# Last child border not showing

Tags: css, css-selectors, border

I am using the selectors `first-child` and `last-child` to apply rounded corners to an unordered list.

The problem I am encountering is that the right hand border of the last list item is not showing.

I define the borders like so:

```
border: 1px solid hotpink;
border-right: 0;
```

Setting the right hand border to 0 to prevent a double bordering, then in the `last-child` I give the `border-right` a width of one.

But this is leaving me without a right-hand border on the last child and I am unsure why, as you can see below:

[image: problem example]

Here's my entire CSS and a JSFiddle:

```
ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 30px;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid hotpink;
    border-right: 0;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.menu li:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

.menu li:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-right: 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QFvr6/

Comment: You could probably avoid all this hassle by applying the border/border-radius to the `ul` instead. Then you just need to do the 'internal' vertical borders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `border-right: 0;` you should use `border-right-width: 0;` and for the `:last-child` selector, you need to use

```
.menu li:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QFvr6/2/)</kbd>

The issue is that when you use `border-right: 0;` it will reset the size, type and the color as well, so even if you use `border-right-width: 1px;` only, it won't work, so you need to use `border-right-width: 0;` for the `.menu li` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your rule is not complete :     `border-right:` **solid** `1px;` or it should be `border-right-width:1px;`
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QFvr6/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, you forgot you specified `border-right` cannot have border:

```
.menu li:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-right: 1px solid #FF69B4;
}
```